# Operador NOT (!)

Tags: javascript

Gente, estou meio sem saber como funciona exatamente o operador not (!). Sempre me confundo na hora de usa-lo porque não sei bem como aplicar. Ele só funciona com parametros igual o typeof()?

Eu sempre uso o != e acho que tecnicamente pode substituir o not... Por exemplo:

```
var tentativas = 0;
var senha = '123';

while(entradasenha != senha){ // como eu poderia usar o (!) aqui?
     if(tentativas > 3) return false;
     var entradasenha = prompt('Digite a senha correta, vc tem 3 tentativas');
     tentativas++;
}
```

Fiz esse codigo só pra exemplificar e saber como eu poderia substituir o != pelo !.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O `!` é o *not*. Ele retorna falso para um valor verdadeiro, e verdadeiro para um valor falso. Em outras palavras, ele "inverte" o valor lógico de uma expressão.

`!=` é *not equal*, ou seja, "não igual", o mesmo que "diferente de".

Estas duas linhas tem o mesmo efeito:

```
while( entradasenha != senha ) {
while( ! ( entradasenha == senha ) ) {
```

**Em resumo:**

- `!=` tem DUAS coisas acontecendo nesta expressão: NOT e EQUAL
- `!` é apenas o NOT.

**Outros exemplos de condições equivalentes:**

- `if( ! ( x > 3 ) )` é o mesmo que `if( x <= 3 )`
- Estas duas linhas têm o mesmo efeito:

  ```
    if ( !cadastrado ) { operacao 1 } else { operacao 2 }
    if ( cadastrado ) { operacao 2 } else { operacao 1 }
  ```

  Uma das vantagens do `!` num `if` como neste último exemplo é se você precisa apenas da condição 2 (executar algo apenas no caso de "cadastrado" ser falso).

  Isso deixa o código um pouco mais elegante em algumas situações, evitando um `{}` vazio ou um `if` com comparação de *[boolean](https://dicionario.priberam.org/booliano)* <sup>1</sup>:

  ```
    if (cadastrado) {} else {return "usuário não cadastrado"}; // sem o !
    if (cadastrado == false) return "usuário não cadastrado" ; // sem o !

    if (!cadastrado) return "usuário não cadastrado";          // usando !
  ```

**De curiosidade:**

Em JavaScript `false` tem o valor `0` e `true` tem o valor `1`, **mas...**
... todo número diferente de zero é considerado `true`.

Veja só os efeitos do `!` e dos *[boolean](https://dicionario.priberam.org/booliano)* nestes casos:

```
VALOR             RESULTA EM
!0                true      
!1                false     
!2                false     
true + true       2
!0 + 2            3
!1 + 2            2
!7 + 2            2
!true             false
!false            true
3 > 2             true
! ( 3 > 2 )       false
! ( ! 0 )         false
! ( ! ( ! 0 ) )   true
```

<sub>1. grafado como ["booliano"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/booliano) (vide sobre Açoriano na mesma página) e listado como ["booleano"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/booleano) em português.</sub>