# O que significa && ! em PHP?

Tags: php, operadores, sintaxe

Estou tentando saber isto, mas aparece em lugar nenhum. Tem um espaço entre && e !.

```
if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
```

Comment: Significa que a condicional seguinte sera uma condição negada, ou seja se a condição for falsa, vira true, se for true, vira false

Comment: No seu caso, Leia assim: **Se for a home** e **não for a pagina frontal** então...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Espaços geralmente não fazem diferença para o código. Pelo menos em PHP quase sempre não. O que até é uma pena porque os programadores fazem atrocidades e tornam o código menos legíveis, inconsistentes. Mais ou menos como fazem com a língua natural. Particularmente eu escreveria assim:

```
if (is_home() && !is_front_page())
```

Fica mais óbvio a associatividade. Pena que se exagerar nisso pode ficar pior.

O `!` (*not*) está negando o resultado de `is_front_page()` que deverá ser um [booleano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214972/101) ou um dado que pode ser representado como um booleano, como 0 ou outro valor.

Como ele é unário será associado ao que estiver à direita e ele tem uma [precedência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/101).

O operador `&&` (*and*) é binário e portanto ele aplicará nas expressões à esquerda e à direita dele. Ele tem uma precedência inferior ao *not*, então será executado depois, se a precedência fosse maior, para obter o mesmo resultado, teria que fazer:

```
is_home() && (!is_front_page()))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/Condition.php).

O espaço não muda a precedência, só conheci uma linguagem que fazia isso e era muito confuso.

Então essa expressão toda precisa que o primeiro método retorne um verdadeiro e o segundo retorne um falso, já que ele será invertido, aí a condição toda do `if` será verdadeira e executará o bloco de código dele.

Na pergunta sobre precedência *linkada* acima tem mais informações sobre o *and*. Tem [sobre o *not* em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37971/101) que funciona igual.

Obviamente que se escrever `&&!` seria outro operador, não tem como o compilador saber que são dois, e como esse operador não existe, daria erro. Esse é um ponto onde o espaço é fundamental. Em tese o compilador poderia saber porque esse operador não existindo ele poderia entender automaticamente que são dois operadores conhecidos que ficou sem espaço. Mas vai que um dia você queira criar um operador `&&!` por alguma razão, não poderia porque ele seria interpretado de forma diferente em algumas situações. Melhor evitar.

Comment: Recomendo esse site http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Por causa de 1 espaço dá pra entender que é um operador novo.

Answer (score 1):

Isso:

```
if (is_home() && ! is_front_page())
```

É a mesma coisa que isso:

```
if (is_home() && !(is_front_page()))
```

Ou seja, por conta do `!`, a condição só vai ser verdadeira caso o `is_home()` retorne verdadeiro e o `is_front_page()` retorne falso.