# Como este operador not está funcionando neste código?

Tags: javascript, operadores, lógica, booleano, operador-lógico

#### Código:

```
var i = 0, finished = false;
    while( (i < acentos.length) && !finished){
```

#### Questão:

Tenho uma variável `bool` recebendo false, e no meu `while` eu estou negando ela.

Se estou negando uma variável false, ela vira `true`, correto?

Ali estou dizendo, enquanto `i` for menor que o tamanho do vetor E `!finished` for `true`, continue?

ou

Enquanto `i` for menor que o tamanho do vetor E `!finished` for `false` continue?

quando eu coloco um variável `bool` dentro de um `while`, ele ignora o valor que foi dado a ela? E define como `true`?.

#### Código completo abaixo:

```
  var i = 0, finished = false; // <-- *IMPORTANTE

        while( (i < acentos.length) && !finished){ // <-- *IMPORTANTE
            if (acentos[i] && acentos[i+1] && acentos[i+2]) {
                selSeat = i;

//Codigo..

                var accept = confirm("Reserva da cadeira "+ (i + 1) +" ~ "+(i + 3)+" está disponível, aceitar?.");

                if (accept) {

                    finished = true; // <-- *IMPORTANTE
                }else{
//Codigo..
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Meu `while` esta assim no começo

```
while(false && true)
```

quando eu aceito os "acentos" e `finished` recebe `true`, logo meu operador de negação nega ele, então ele fica como `false`, ai meu `while` fica assim

```
while( false && false)
```

como as duas condições são iguais ele sai do *loop*? Posso estar viajando, mas, estou tentando pensar como a lógica funciona.

Comment: Comece por https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37971/operador-not . Not inverte o valor, !finished => enquanto não finished => enquanto finished for falso

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Operador NOT (!)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37971/operador-not)

Comment: minha dúvida não era sobre o operador not em si, eu sei que ele "inverte" os valores,mas acho que o bigown respondeu minha dúvida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> se estou negando uma variável false, ela vira `true` correto?

Não, você está invertendo o valor contido na variável, você não altera a variável.

> Ali estou dizendo, enquanto `i` for menor que o tamanho do vetor E !finished for true continue?

Isso, mas eu leria "enquanto i for menor que o tamanho do vetor E não for finished". Ou melhor ainda, "enquanto i for menor que o tamanho do vetor E não for finalizado", tem que decidir se vai de inglês ou português.

> Enquanto `i` for menor que o tamanho do vetor E `!finished` for `false` continue?

Não, essa leitura está errada. Só pode executar se tudo for verdadeiro. Então não pode analisar como `false`.

> quando eu coloco um variável *bool* dentro de um `while`, ele ignora o valor que foi dado a ela? e define como `true`?.

Isso não faz muito sentido. Nada é ignorado. "Colocar" é um termo muito ambíguo. A linha `finished = true;` está atribuindo `true` para a variável, provavelmente mudando o seu valor, pelo menos ao que dá para ver neste código. E isso terá consequência na condição.

> meu while esta assim no começo `while(false && true)`

Não sei, mas acredito que ambos são `true`

> ai meu while fica assim `while( false && false)`

Isso é mais difícil analisar só com esse trecho. Mas é pra ficar `true` e `false`, o que encerrará o laço.

> como as duas condições são iguais ele sai do *loop*?

Não, ele sai quando um dele é falso, por isso que a afirmação anterior está errado, se uma delas for falsa logo de cara nem entra no laço a primeira vez.

O `&&` exige que tanto o operando da direita quanto o da esquerda sejam verdadeiros para dar verdadeiro, segundo a [tabela verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101).

```
true && true = true
true && false = false
false && false = false
false && true = false
```

Todo o código pode ser melhor escrito. Inclusive não precisa dessa variável de *flag* `finished`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < acentos.length; i++) {
    if (acentos[i] && acentos[i + 1] && acentos[i + 2]) {
        selSeat = i; //tenho medo desta variável solta
        //Codigo..
        if (confirm("Reserva da cadeira " + (i + 1) + " ~ " + (i + 3) + " está disponível, aceitar?.")) {
            break;
        } else {
            //Codigo..
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101).

Comment: Então a lógica seria assim, no começo meu while esta assim, while( true && true), e depois quando finished recebe true, o while passa a ficar assim while(true && false) ? como ambos não são true ele sai do loop.

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus como um deles não é `true` ele sai.

Comment: isso, eu utilizei `break;` no lugar de `finished`, estou seguindo os passos de use a cabeca js, por isso do finished, ele me mostra diferentes opções, tem algo no javascript que eu possa verificar os valores da condição while? como se fosse um var_dump do php só que com while. @Edit Obrigado por esclarecer minhas dúvidas, essas palavras apesar de óbvias me fizeram ver de outro modo o código.. _Só pode executar se tudo for verdadeiro._

Comment: a variável solta é variável de controle  `if (selSeat >= 0) {
  selSeat = -1;
  initSeats();
 }`

Comment: @ onde ela foi declarada? Isso pode ser um problema. Você sempre pode mandar imprimir os valores no momento que quiser.  Tem opções de *debug* em alguns IDEs e navegadores, mas como não tenho feito nada em JS não sei como está a praticidade disso. Na época que fiz algo em JS era ruim. Minha intenção é sempre responder de forma que a pessoa veja as coisas de outra forma, porque é muito comum quem está aprendendo ter ideias confusas ainda.

Comment: ela está como variável global fora da função/método, não sabia sobre debugger.. muito útil, achei ele no chrome  e já verifiquei os valores, while(true & true) e dps quando finished recebe true, fica while(true  && false), muito obrigado mais uma vez..

Comment: Esse era meu medo.

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus como você nunca aceitou uma resposta em perguntas suas, dê uma olhada no [tour] como o site funciona. Revise todas sus perguntas. Aceita a que melhor te respondeu, se alguma respondeu. Não tenha pressa, só não esqueça de fazer para ajudar a comunidade identificar a que foi melhor para você. Inclusive você pode votar em tudo que achar útil em todo o site.

Comment: verifiquei o tour, bem interessante, já avaliei esse post. Com relação ao seu medo de variável global, qual foi sua experiência com ela? até então, não vejo problema em utilizar.

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32251/101

Comment: interessante, não sabia sobre global sem o uso de `var`, no meu código acho que não tem problema, `//variavel global var selSeat = -1;
function findSeat() {
 if (selSeat >= 0) {
  selSeat = -1;
  initSeats();
 } // + código abaixo.`, me interessei por essa coisa de top-level, depois irei pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score 1):

O `!` sempre vai negar a expressão que vem a frente, portanto:

```
finished = true;
//!finished = false
finished = false;
//!finished = true;
```

Comment: Sim sim, a questão não era essa, quando estou com dúvidas não consigo expressar muito bem elas, desculpe, o bigown acho que respondeu minha dúvida com essas palavras aqui >> Só pode executar se tudo for verdadeiro

Answer (score 0):

Duas negações são transformadas em uma afirmação.
ex: Not false -> verdadeiro
not 2 != 2-> not (falso) -> verdadeiro (dois é igual a dois, então retorna um valor falso).
Sendo assim, ali no while, já que é utilizado o &&(and), o valor de finished tem que ser falso para cair no código interno.

Answer (score 0):

> Tenho uma variável bool recebendo false, e no meu while eu estou negando ela. A dúvida é a seguinte, se estou negando uma variável false, ela vira true correto?

quando você usa o ! você inverte o valor dela, se era true vira false e se era false vira true.

> Ali estou dizendo, enquanto i for menor que o tamanho do vetor E !finished for true continue?
>   ou
>   Enquanto i for menor que o tamanho do vetor E !finished for false continue?

Você está dizendo enquanto i for menor que o tamanho o vetro e finalizado **não** for verdadeiro continua.

> quando eu coloco um variável bool dentro de um while, ele ignora o valor que foi dado a ela? e define como true?

Não.

> Deixa eu ver se entendi.., meu while esta assim no começo while(false && true)
>
> quando eu aceito os "acentos" e finished recebe true, logo meu operador de negação nega ele, então ele fica como false, ai meu while fica assim while( false && false)
>
> como as duas condições são iguais ele sai do loop? posso estar viajando, mas.. estou tentando pensar como a lógica funciona.

false e true é igual a false.
Se você quiser que execute caso qualquer uma seja true use ou:
false ou true é igual a true.

Comment: Pensa comigo, finished é inicializado como false correto? `finished = false`, quando eu coloco essa condição no `while( !finished ) `, qual valor boleano(true ou false) você encherga ali?   `while ( ? )`

Comment: Como já disseram !false é igual a true. Então fica while(true).

Comment: isso, minha dúvida era porque a condição sai do while, quando finished recebe true, e como fiquei confuso acabei esquecendo que, independente da condição que foi dada, seja ela uma condição booleana ou não, o while com o operador lógico && só continua se os dois forem verdadeiros.(nesse caso).